# Is it possible to open a text file in the current terminal by using xdg-open

Tags: shell

I'm wondering if it is possible to open a text file in the current terminal (e.g. with vim) by using xdg-open ?

I'd like to get rid of of my workaround (a custom shell script)

```
filename="$1"

case "${filename##*.}" in
    ods)
        open "$filename"
        ;;
    *)
        vim "$filename"
        ;;
esac
```